# ArangoDB breaks the computer

Tags: arangodb

I can't work on my computer because arangoDB consumes all the resources of my PC:
[disk usage up to 100 mb/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iZPQ.png)

Besides, ArangoDB fills storage memory bit by bit up to full filling.

And when memory had completely filled I can log in to 127.0.0.1:8529

Also I can stop service and process but not at once.

[a lot of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUV96.png)

What's wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening without further information. What is the workload you are using ArangoDB for, e.g. are there lots of incoming writes, to how many collections, and of what size (approx) are they? What version of ArangoDB are you using?

Comment: May be, service of monitoring (request every 1 second) has killed him?

Comment: Version 3.1.23 that I removed

Comment: It would still be good to know what workload was running on the server. As far as I understand from the above you were sending one request to the server every second. Was that request writing to the database or reading from it? What other operations were ongoing in ArangoDB at the time the problem occurred? Do you use it to run any AQL queries or other document operations, and of what size/volume?

Comment: The service of monitoring (the heartbeat module) is built-in the system from the foxx package manager.

https://cookbook.wdt.io/arangodb.html

Comment: Not one query I have used

Comment: Mmmh. That heartbeat module does not even read from the database or write to it when running. So it should not produce any writes nor WAL logfiles. Do you happen to know if there were any log messages in ArangoDB's error log (or the Windows event log) and/or if the problem is reproducible?

Comment: I didn't do anything more.

Now, I'll install ArangoDB again and try to read the file "logfile-2887190.db" that I saved apart

Comment: After reinstallation, ArangoDB works well. Can't read the log file from that jounal. I'll not deal with the problem any more. The issue is closed. Thank you, stj!